# Bootstrap Carousel not working after adding items dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap Carousel as shown below

```html
<div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel3">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <img src='images/image1.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <img src='images/image2.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <img src='images/image3.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
              </div>
```

It works fine as it is but when I add images with jQuery by appending same html blocks as shown below it doesn't work anymore:

```html
$('#myContent').append("<div class='carousel slide multi-item-carousel' id='theCarousel3'><div class='carousel-inner'>");

  for(var x = 0; x < imageCount; x++) {
    var imgElement = "<div class='item'><div class='col-lg-4'><img src='"
                      + pictures[x].path + "' id='img" + x +
                      "' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' /></div></div>";
    
    $('#myContent').append(imgElement);
    if(x == 0) $('#theCarousel3 .item').addClass('active');
  }

  $('#myContent').append("</div><a class='left carousel-control' href='#theCarousel3' data-slide='prev'></a><a class='right carousel-control' href='#theCarousel3' data-slide='next'></a></div>");
```

I have even added the active class for the first item which seem to me a possible issue but still not working, what I see is images added one by one but not sliding. What could be the issue here, any help please? Thanks.

Comment: You're appending your `imgElement` 's to `#myContent`, not to the `.carousel-inner` you create in line 1, so you're not creating the same DOM tree as shown above. Same goes for your `.carousel-control` - those belong to `.carousel` and not to `#myContent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add you images to the same DOM element as you other images.

instead of `$('#myContent').append(imgElement);` it should be

`$('#theCarousel3 .carousel-inner').eq(0).append(imageElement);`

You may be able to get rid of the `eq(0)` part, but I'm not sure if that will work since class selector is multiple.

the other option is to add the `myContent` id to your carousel-inner element

you also arent creating valid html the way you are trying to create the carousel

try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var imgElement,
    pictures = [
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png',
      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Rz-Ob1uRO2Xch40qHYgxpZitc3vZzxjeeSHVaNazn4dUny-AqGK0hLXUxhTpg4qgATP6VdlvZPYv_o0=s559-no',
      'http://blog.suite-logique.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/G7N0lnxM.jpeg',
      'http://inspiratron.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/google-hummingbird.jpg'
    ]
    wrapper = $('#myContent'),
    carousel = $('<div/>', {
      id: "theCarousel3",
      "class": "carousel slide multi-item-carousel",
      append: '<div class="carousel-inner"></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel3" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel3" data-slide="next"></a>'
    }),
    carouselInner = carousel.find('.carousel-inner').eq(0);

  wrapper.append(carousel);
  carousel.carousel();
  for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    imgElement = $('<div/>', {
      "class": "item" + (i ? '' : ' active'),
      append: $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'col-lg-4',
        append: $('<img/>', {
          src: pictures[i],
          id: 'img' + i,
          "class": 'img-responsive',
          height: 300
        })
      })
    })
    carouselInner.append(imgElement);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id='myContent'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I corrected that but now I see only one still image instead of multiple images sliding. I even copied back the html blocks which were being appended through jQuery and put them as static html and it works fine !! Crazy isn't it.

Comment: ok i just noticed you arent creating valid html i tghough you were only adding images to an existing carousel. updated answer

Comment: @aliencity please mark this answer as accepted unless there is something still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Note: Frist div have 'item' and 'active' class, and all other div have only 'item' class then it will work otherwise it will not work.

```
             <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <img src='images/image1.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <img src='images/image2.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <img src='images/image3.jpg' id='img' class='img-responsive' width='250' height='300' />
                </div>
```

Its working for me, hopefully it will also work for you. Thank you!!!!!!!!