# HTML carousel with jQuery doesn't change image

Tags: javascript, html, css, jstl

I'm trying to make a carousel with some images from a servlet. I managed to create the carousel, but the image doesn't change. Is always the first image from array. I did  get the code from din article: [Bootstrap Carousel not working after adding items dynamically with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926770/bootstrap-carousel-not-working-after-adding-items-dynamically-with-jquery). But I'm not allowed to comment at the article. :(

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id='myContent'></div>
</div>
<p>${offer.toString()}</p>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
     wrapper = $('#myContent'),
     carousel = $('<div/>', { id: "theCarousel3", "class": "carousel slide multi-item-carousel",
         append:'<div class="carousel-inner"></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel3" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel3"data-slide="next"></a>' }), 
     carouselInner =carousel.find('.carousel-inner').eq(0); wrapper.append(carousel);
    carousel.carousel(); for (var i = 0; i <${houseImages.size()}; i++) {
    imgElement = $('<div />', { "class": "item" + (i ? '' : ' active'),
        append: $('<div/>', { "class": 'col-lg-4', append: $('<img/>', {
          src:'data:image/jpg;base64,${houseImages.get(i)}', id: 'img' + i,
          "class": 'img-responsive',
          height: 300
        })
      })
    })
    carouselInner.append(imgElement);
  }
})
</script>
```

Update: I use owlcarousel.

Comment: C'mon mate format your code if you want people to look at it. Put through https://prettier.io/playground/ at least. Takes 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry. Now is better?

Comment: Its looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set the first slide with active class.

Try change this:

```
"class": "item" + (i ? '' : ' active')
```

to

```
"class": "item" + (i == 0 ? ' active' : ''),
```

Comment: I did. Still not working... In the browser console the class divs are changing when I press left or right. So maybe not this is the problem...

Comment: I put your code into a jsfiddle and it works, look: https://jsfiddle.net/xpxzyock/1/

I just change the src path and the ${houseImages.size()} for '5'.

So, if u can see the images, the problem isint' on this code. Try remove other css styles from your code, leave just the bootstrap.css.

Comment: I don't have other css styles. When I display the images in jstl tags like this :                                                                                <c:forEach var="element" items="${houseImages}">
  <img id="image" src="data:image/jpg;base64,${element}">
</c:forEach>                                                                                              I can see all the images.

Comment: So, run your code and put here the html generated please.

Comment: Here: https://codeshare.io/axbkwX . Indeed is some css style, but is from another page that I included. I have tried to erase her, but didn't change anything.

Comment: My bad, I want to see the code what is appended on the '<div id='myContent'></div>'. Use the elements inspector after the javascript generate the html.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5w0D67     Is this that do you need? The image src doesn't change...

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to check this part of code. Tell me, what's the class 'multi-item-carousel' for?
And my last idea for now. Try change the `class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel"` for `class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"`

Comment: I don't really know the usage for this class... I did change it as you said. Still no difference. Maybe the jstl variable is the problem. I don't know jquerry, this is my first experience.

Comment: Your jQuery code looks right. If you just run your jQuery code in a jsfiddle for example, you see it works perfectly. Like here https://jsfiddle.net/xpxzyock/1/

A few months ago, I experienced a similar problem with the Bootstrap carousel and my problem at that time was related to my custom css. Because of this, I think the problem is related to your css.

Other option is use other carousel, like the https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I will manage to solve it I will post here the solution.  I will try the your suggestion  about other carousel.

Comment: With owl carousel everything works  perfect! Thank you @FrancisGregori !

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore `${houseImages.size()}` isn't defined in your snippet, therefore your loop isn't running at all.

Comment: In the browser console I can see I can see its value. Is a jstl variable. Or maybe I wrong. Can you please  gime some details?

Comment: Your uploaded code doesn't contain this function anymore, therefore I think it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: But your code does contain two `body`-tags and the `myContent`-id is used twice.
Try to reduce it to one element respectively, it should work :)

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the body mistake. Can you tell me that do you mean by "myContent-id is used twice"?

Comment: I spotted the following things:

- everybody can edit code from codeshare (and I cut everything into my editor, but reversed it now)

- you have the `myContent`-id in line 109 & 256

- you have the `image`-id in lines 116, 118, 120, 263, 265 & 267

- you are loading jQuery 1.11.0 (line 3 & 154) and 2.1.1 (line 123 & 270)

- you are loading bootstrap 3.3.7 two times, but each time the same version (therefore no real conflict)

Comment: Cleaned code: https://jsfiddle.net/Syndesi/pevm895a/
(and it's working with the 3 identical images)

Comment: My mistake ... I copied the code twice in codeshare.